# Mule parsing Incoming REST request

Tags: mule

I have a REST client that is preparing payload in JSON format and invoking a REST service. My job is to create the REST service in Mule. I need some information on how I can map the incoming Payload to a java object so that I can invoke the REST service component class and get the values passed in the JSON object. Does the payload after HTTP inbound endpoint already contain the JSON values sent by the client? In which case a simple JSON to Object mapper would map it as Hashmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will most likely need to create a custom transformer for this use case if you have a special use case.

See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Creating+Custom+Transformer+Class

If you get sent JSON you can convert it into a custom class like this:

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer name="jsonToFruitCollection" returnClass="
org.mule.module.json.transformers.FruitCollection"/>
```

Comment: I am able to get the JSONData (in String) - is there an easy way to convert it to an Object (Array List or Hash Map) on which I can use the mule expressions?. One option I see is to use Google GSON and convert it to object. Wondering if there is an easier way

Comment: you need to specify the type for that transformer, see http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/json/JsonToObjectTransformer.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively You can also use ObjectMapper and can probably use a bean to map your JSON directly to your Java object in your Java class.

You can also use `<json:json-to-object-transformer/>` directly after your Http inbound endpoint, parse and get each element value in your Mule flow and store in variables. Then these variables can be passed into your Java class where you can map these to your Java object easily.

Both the approach will work fine